# Setting a component to "float" on screen and not take space

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create an application in React Native, and I have one screen, where I have header, flat list and a card component.

I have the flat list and card component in the same safe area view. I want the flat list to take the whole screen (starting below the header) and the card component to "float" there.

I can't really figure out how to do it (new to React Native), currently, because of the flex box (I guess) the card component takes part of the screen, so the list is starting below the header and ends above the card.

This is what it looks like now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4xZu.jpg

I want the list to continue behind the card component.

This is how I layout things right now:

```
return (
    <>
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.meetingDetailsContainer}>
        <ListHeader meeting={meeting} />
 
        <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
          {members.length > 0 ? (
            <FlatList
              data={members}
              renderItem={renderItem}
              keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
              showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
              onScroll={(event) =>
                setInfoCardHeight(-event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y)
              }
            />
          ) : (
            <Text style={styles.noParticipantsText}>No participants yet.</Text>
          )}
        </View>
        <View style={{bottom: infoCardHeight, backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}>
          <InfoCard meeting={meeting} />
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
)
```

I need the list to go behind the card because I made the card component to "disappear" when the user scrolls, but then I have a white blank space on the screen because the list ends where the card starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to render something on top of another, use absolute position instead of the default relative one.

```js
    <View style={{ position: 'absolute', bottom: 0, top: infoCardHeight, left: 0, right: 0 }}>
      <InfoCard meeting={meeting} />
    </View>
```

When the card wrapper doesn't take relative space from the parent View, the wrapper View of FlatList will automatically expand to the bottom of the screen.